# Condense/merge cells in a table in R

Tags: r, split

I'm trying to do something with a table in R.

The table comes into the script like this

```
          M   P
Position1 34  56
Position2 45  23
Position3 89  78
Position1 56  45
Position3 54  35
Position2 56  89
```

And after analyzing this script, ideally, I'd like a final output to be this:

```
          M   P
Position1 90  101
Position2 101 102
Position3 143 113
```

Basically I sum the total number across the positions for M and P. I was wondering if there was an easier way to do this. The positions will be at random. Is there a way to potentially split the data table by the position?

Comment: Your feedback will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'aggregate' which needs to be used as follows:

```
> ddf
         V1 V2 V3
1 Position1 34 56
2 Position2 45 23
3 Position3 89 78
4 Position1 56 45
5 Position3 54 35
6 Position2 56 89


> a1 = aggregate(V2~V1, ddf, sum)
> a2 = aggregate(V3~V1, ddf, sum)
> merge(a1, a2)
         V1  V2  V3
1 Position1  90 101
2 Position2 101 112
3 Position3 143 113
```

Comment: I used this, and it worked! Ideally, I'd check all there, because it seemed that all three worked. Thank you guys so much!

Comment: -1 for a very convoluted (and very likely, slow) approach to doing `aggregate(. ~ V1, ddf, sum)`.

Comment: Which of all these approaches will be fastest on benchmarks?

Comment: @rnso, at scale, the "data.table" and "dplyr" approaches, although `tapply` does quite well too.

Comment: `merge` in base R is not a particularly fast function.

Comment: @rnso, I've added some benchmarks [at this Gist](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/6282a022b2eadb0fe1c6). "data.table" is the clear winner.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `summarise_each` from `dplyr` if you have multiple columns and you have a big dataset and of course the data is `data.frame` (From the post, it is not clear whether you have a `matrix` or `data.frame`)

```
library(dplyr)
 dat %>% 
      group_by(Pos) %>% 
      summarise_each(funs(sum=sum(., na.rm=TRUE)))
 #        Pos   M   P
 #1 Position1  90 101
 #2 Position2 101 112
 #3 Position3 143 113
```

Or another option I would use for bigger datasets is `data.table`.  From the benchmarks by @Ananda Mahto, it is the clear winner in speed.

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(dat)[, lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm=TRUE), by=Pos]
 #        Pos   M   P
 #1: Position1  90 101
 #2: Position2 101 112
 #3: Position3 143 113
```

If you are using a `matrix` and do not need to transform it to `data.frame` with creating a new column for `row.names`.  (Perhaps, that option would still be efficient)

```
  do.call(rbind, by(m1, list(rownames(m1)), colSums, na.rm=TRUE))
  #            M   P
  #Position1  90 101
  #Position2 101 112
  #Position3 143 113
```

Or a slightly more efficient method when dealing with `matrices`

```
   library(reshape2)
   acast(melt(m1), Var1~Var2, value.var="value", sum, na.rm=TRUE)
   #           M   P
   #Position1  90 101
   #Position2 101 112
   #Position3 143 113
```

#### data

The rownames are added as a column as `data.frame` won't allow duplicate rownames.

```
dat <- structure(list(Pos = c("Position1", "Position2", "Position3", 
"Position1", "Position3", "Position2"), M = c(34L, 45L, 89L, 
56L, 54L, 56L), P = c(56L, 23L, 78L, 45L, 35L, 89L)), .Names = c("Pos", 
"M", "P"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))


m1 <- structure(c(34, 45, 89, 56, 54, 56, 56, 23, 78, 45, 35, 89), .Dim = c(6L, 
2L), .Dimnames = list(c("Position1", "Position2", "Position3", 
"Position1", "Position3", "Position2"), c("M", "P")))
```

Comment: I've added some benchmarks [at this Gist](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/6282a022b2eadb0fe1c6). "data.table" is the clear winner. It would be nice when you are sharing this many options to also make a little bit more of commentary on which one you would ultimately recommend in which types of situations.

Comment: @Ananda Mahto Thanks for sharing the benchmarks.  I will add some commentary.

Answer (score 1):

One more, just for fun.  This one produces the structure you show in the post.

```
t(sapply(split(dat[-1], dat$Pos), colSums))
#             M   P
# Position1  90 101
# Position2 101 112
# Position3 143 113
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer only applies if you are dealing with a `matrix` (like the "m1" dataset shared in @akrun's answer):

```
xtabs(Freq ~ Var1 + Var2, data.frame(as.table(m1)))
#            Var2
# Var1          M   P
#   Position1  90 101
#   Position2 101 112
#   Position3 143 113
```

Answer (score 0):

First get your rownames

```
rows<-unique(rownames(yourDataFrame))
```

Make sure unique is there or we'll get a lot of duplicates

Then you can do a couple of different things here, the package plyr would come in handy, but just using base R you can use lapply to calculate your sums

```
result<-lapply(rownames, function(rname){
         subsetDF<-yourDataFrame[rname,]
         apply(subsetDF, 2, sum)
    }
)
```

To break it down, you take all your rownames, and in lapply subset your dataframe by just the rows of that rowname.  Next, you apply sum over that subset, taking the columns, and then output that to a list.  You could then do something like rbindlist(result) to get your resulting dataframe.

Definitely not the most efficient way to do it, but it's the first thing I thought of

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the aggregate function.

Say you have your table stored as `data` then try

```
condensedData <- aggregate(data, by=list(position), FUN=sum, na.rm=TRUE)
```

If that doesn't do exactly what you want, try experimenting with the aggregate function. The important inputs are `by` and `FUN`. `by` tells `aggregate` which columns you want the result to be identified uniquely by, while `FUN` tells `aggregate` what to do to combine numbers with the same `by`. `FUN` can be "sum", "mean", etc...

Comment: I guess you meant `aggregate(data[,-1], by=list(Pos=data[,1]), FUN=sum, na.rm=TRUE)`